# Not able to debug code in Eclipse linux Error cant find source malloc.c

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, malloc

I am using ECLIPSE IDE on ubuntu
I have written simple code to create tree head.
Code is getting compiled successfully. But while debugging it give an error when ever it executes malloc statement.

Error

Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/glibc-2.19/malloc/malloc.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

```
    /*
 * tree.c

 *
 *  Created on: 04-Dec-2014
 *      Author: etron
 */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node
{
    int key_value;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *left;
};
struct node *root=0;

struct node* insert(int key,struct node **leaf)
{
    if(*leaf == 0)
    {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        (*leaf)->key_value = key;
        (*leaf)->left = 0;
        (*leaf)->right = 0;
        return 0;
    }
}


void  main()
{
    struct node *bt=0;
    int i=100;


    insert(i,&bt);

}
```

Comment: if you remove the `malloc` header file, is the compiler showing any error messages?

Comment: There's little to be gained from debugging into malloc. Just don't try to step into malloc. Your main is wrong. `int main(void)`. And don't cast the return value of malloc. Enable and heed compiler warnings. It will complain about you not returning from insert. `malloc` is declared by `stdlib.h`. Why include `malloc.h`?

Comment: IMO, you should either strip your glibc, or have the source files available if you you't want your debugger to barf.

Comment: I have tried it wihout <malloc.h> it gives the same error. int main does not make any change, also tried without type casting of malloc but still gettiong error while step into execution when reaches to malloc()  statement.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you Sir It worked with step Over Run

Comment: @user1551103 You don't understand me. I'm telling you that `void main()` is wrong. It's unrelated to your debugging problems. It was extra free advice. Take it or leave it.

Comment: the insert() function has many problems.  Amongst them are: 1) there is an execution path that is missing a return (value) statement.  2) the returned value from malloc() should, for several reasons, not be cast.  3) the returned value from malloc should be checked to assure successful operation, otherwise, the following code could be accessing an offset from address 0.  Also, the code is changing 'leaf' back in the caller (main()) and never returns a pointer to some malloc'd memory, which the return value type implies

Comment: this code does not cleanly compile due to two warnings: 1) return value from main (void) is not 'int'  2) control reaches end of non-void function.

Comment: main ignores the returned value from insert()

Comment: @user1551103 if correcting the return type from main() made no difference, then you need to correct your method of compiling such that all warning are enabled.  Note: warning should not be ignored.

Comment: the global variable 'root' is never used.   Note: a pointer is not a integer.  So any pointers should be set to NULL not 0.

Answer (score 2):

There's little to be gained from debugging into malloc. Just don't try to step into malloc. Your main is wrong. `int main(void)`. And don't cast the return value of malloc. Enable and heed compiler warnings. It will complain about you not returning from insert. `malloc` is declared by `stdlib.h`. Why include `malloc.h`?
                    – David Heffernan

Thank you Sir It worked with step Over Run
                    – user1551103